# Unable to get Goatcounter to work on Github pages website

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, goatcounter

I deployed my personal website (React Typescript) through Github pages [here](https://github.com/astronights/astronights.github.io/tree/main) and I wanted to add Goatcounter to me website.

I added this line of code to my [`index.html`](https://github.com/astronights/astronights.github.io/blob/main/public/index.html) to enable Goatcounter.

```
<script data-goatcounter="https://astronights.goatcounter.com/count" async src="//gc.zgo.at/count.js"></script>
```

But I'm unable to access the Goatcounter domain, the Goatcounter site does not exist.
[image]

Am I missing something? Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: [You **absolutely** need to specify a `integrity="<secure-hash>"` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) on all externally-loaded `<script>` elements, otherwise your site will get hacked when the external CDN that you're depending on goes down.

Comment: _"I'm unable to access the Goatcounter domain."_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Edited with more details. Thank you.

Comment: [The documentation says](https://www.goatcounter.com/help/start) you should have `<script data-goatcounter="https://MYCODE.goatcounter.com/count"` - is `astronights` your actual value for `MYCODE`? If so, then [you should contact them and file a bug](https://www.goatcounter.com/contact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `astronights.goatcounter.com` is a sub domain specific to your site `astronights.com`, Although attached error SS points out that goatcounter.com doesn't exposes this sub domain yet.

As per first paragraph of goatcounter [Readme](https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter#readme), you need to either host the app your self OR you need to sign up and register your Code (astronights) like shown in attached SS, If not done already. Make sure `https://astronights.goatcounter.com` is accessible before loading it in your index.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Once I signed up on goatcounter.